# Specified cast exception in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hope everybody is pretty good.

Well, I am getting a weird 'Specified Cast is not valid.' exception in one of my LINQ queries.

The code is as follows:

```
public string GetFiscalYearID(string fiscalYear)
{
    int fYear = Convert.ToInt32(fiscalYear);
    DataTable dtFiscalYearID = new DataTable();
    dtFiscalYearID = DomainBL.GetDomainDataFromFieldName("FiscalYearId");
    **var item = from r in dtFiscalYearID.AsEnumerable()
               where r.Field<Int32>("FiscalYearNumber") == fYear
               select r.Field<Int32>("FiscalYearId");**//Exception at this line
    if (item.ToList().Count> 0)
    {
        return item.ToList()[0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here, **dtFiscalYearID** gets a DataTable from the DB which has just 2 columns namely, **FiscalYearId** and **FiscalYearNumber**. DataTypes of FiscalYearId and FiscalYearNumber are tinyint and smallint respectively.

When item is expanded, I see the Specified Cast exception, I tried Int16 too, but it too throws me an exception.

Can experts here tell me what might be wrong in the above code?
Any pointers or such will be quite appreciated.

Regards
Anurag

Comment: Check if any null value is returned?

Comment: Use `r["FiscalYearNumber"]` and `r["FiscalYearId"]` instead.

Comment: I think you can check the type of the field using `dtFiscalYearID.Rows[0]["FiscalYearId"].GetType()`.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help..The issue has been dealt with...@Gert Arnold..I will try your option too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (int) r.Field<byte>("FiscalYearId")
```

`tinyint` is byte in c#, bytes can be casted to `int` directly

EDIT:

According to this list: [MSDN mapping CLR parameter list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), tinyint is mapped to Byte. I think that line with where is also corrupted cause you are trying to convert `smallint` to int32.

```
where r.Field<Int16>("FiscalYearNumber") == fYear
```

`Int16` is equivalent to `smallint`.

Comment: Mr Wudzik, the above solution doesn't work actually, I tried variants of your solution too, but to vain, the Specified Cast Exception occurs. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Mr Wudzik, I will try again with the Edit stuff

Comment: Hello Mr Wudzik, the edit stuff worked, but I wana know can't we map Int16 to Int32, I have a notion that small datatypes can be implicitly mapped into bigger datatypes...

Comment: mapped != casted, you can cast int16 to int32

Comment: Gotcha Mr Wudzik...Thanks

Comment: What happened Mr Wudzik?

Comment: @Anurag someone is downvoting my answers ;/

Comment: Ohh I see..well there will be spammers and else, don't you pay heed to them..you can maybe report it to the StackOverflow authorities..you are doing a great work..Cheers